# Pictures of all airplanes, organized by tail number

Tags: data-request, images, public-transport, aviation

Whenever a plane crash happens, Wikipedia and Wikinews articles are created within minutes, and good reusable pictures of the aircraft become needed.

Is there a database/website that has pictures for as many aircraft as possible?

- Pictures must be easily findable by [tail number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_registration).
- License must be compatible with either CC-BY-SA or GFDL.

Bonus if a web interface allows one to type a tail number and browse the gallery (thumbnails) of images that match it.

[image: Tail number D-AIPX]
*(aircraft with tail number "D-AIPX", by SEBASTIEN MORTIER, May 2014, [CC BY-SA 2.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0), [via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3A320_GERMANWINGS_D-AIPX_147_10_05_14_BCN_RIP_(16730197959).jpg))*

Answer (score 3):

Most commercial aricraft, lots of military and some general aviation aircraft.

[Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/)

Comment: Nice website, but unfortunately [their pictures are not at all open](http://www.airliners.net/usephotos/).

Comment: "CC-BY-SA or GFDL" - Now I get it. That's the licensing for use. In some weird way I thought it was a format for aircraft registration.